# NPM Proxy Issue - Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium and I just installed npm from the official website. I tried installing some modules via npm and it displays the below logs.

I don't have any proxy configured till now. I'm using my home internet connection. **I'm not under corporate proxy!!!**

====Executing command 'npm install'====

```
npm WARN package.json NerdRoom@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem but i´m behind proxy but trying to fix that problem maybe can help you, put this command:

```
nmp config get proxy
```

if you have previously poxy configuration it show you the preview configuration like this:

```
http://Domain/User username:password@host:port
```

this is one example, can be other too. The point is if you have previously proxy configurations you need type this command:

```
npm config set proxy null
```

and it has to work fine because if you don't have proxy it has to work without problems. I hope this help you.